# Firebase messaging campaign doesn't deliver iOS notifications

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to set up a messaging campaign in Firebase - to display daily notification for users, at specific time in user's local time. I started with a campaign for both Android and iOS apps - and Android works fine, as expected. On iOS it doesn't show notifications, even if it shows number of sent - still opened is zero. Later I've set up another one, only for iOS devices - same result.

Interestingly - in the first step of setting up the campaign I can send a test message - and it is delivered as expected (with specified FCM token). However still doesn't trigger daily notifications - no delivery to any device.

Any suggestions?